# while making debian package from source i'm seeing the error

Tags: packaging, deb

While making Debian package I'm seeing the below error.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-232-76-3:/opt/uat/elasticsearch-1.4.4$ sudo dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -us -uc

dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package elasticsearch
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.4.4-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Ubuntu <ubuntu@unknown>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build elasticsearch-1.4.4
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
        rm -f debian/elasticsearch.substvars
        rm -f debian/elasticsearch.*.debhelper
        rm -rf debian/elasticsearch/
        rm -f debian/*.debhelper.log
        rm -f debian/files
        find .  \( \( -type f -a \
                \( -name '#*#' -o -name '.*~' -o -name '*~' -o -name DEADJOE \
                 -o -name '*.orig' -o -name '*.rej' -o -name '*.bak' \
                 -o -name '.*.orig' -o -name .*.rej -o -name '.SUMS' \
                 -o -name TAGS -o \( -path '*/.deps/*' -a -name '*.P' \) \
                \) -exec rm -f {} \; \) -o \
                \( -type d -a -name autom4te.cache -prune -exec rm -rf {} \; \) \)
        rm -f *-stamp
 debian/rules build
dh build
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
   dh_auto_test
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary
   dh_testroot
   dh_prep
        rm -f debian/elasticsearch.substvars
        rm -f debian/elasticsearch.*.debhelper
        rm -rf debian/elasticsearch/
   dh_installdirs
        install -d debian/elasticsearch
   dh_auto_install
   dh_install
        install -d debian/elasticsearch/etc/init.d
        cp -a ./debian/elasticsearch.x debian/elasticsearch/etc/init.d/
   dh_installdocs
        install -g 0 -o 0 -d debian/elasticsearch/usr/share/doc/elasticsearch
        cp -a PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin debian/elasticsearch/usr/share/doc/elasticsearch
cp: cannot stat `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin': No such file or directory
dh_installdocs: cp -a PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin debian/elasticsearch/usr/share/doc/elasticsearch returned exit code 1
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to set PATH in your debian/docs file.